# What is happening with this plot's incorrect ordering when `.sort_values()` is used?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm lucky to have caught this mistake in my data analysis:

I'm making three bar plots. Pearson's correlation, Spearman's correlation and then a plot showing the difference of S-P for each variable.

To create the visualization, I've used the following lines of code. Of particular note is my use of the agument `data=cor.sort_values(by='SomeMeasureHere')`

```
def plot_response_corr(df, features, response, corr_type):

    cor = pd.DataFrame()

    # Measure difference between Spearman's and Pearson's to analyze for non-linearity
    if corr_type == 's-p':

        cor['feature'] = features
        cor['spearman'] = [df[f].corr(df[response], 'spearman') for f in features]
        cor['pearson'] = [df[f].corr(df[response], 'pearson') for f in features]
        cor['comparison'] = cor['spearman'] - cor['pearson']


        fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3, sharex=True, figsize=(12, 4), )
        [ax.tick_params('x', labelrotation=45) for ax in axes]

        sns.barplot(
            data=cor, 
            x='feature', y='comparison', ax=axes[2]
        ).set_title('S-P Comparison')

        sns.barplot(
            data=cor,
            x='feature', y='spearman', ax=axes[1]
        ).set_title('Spearman Association')

        sns.barplot(
            data=cor,
            x='feature', y='pearson', ax=axes[0]
        ).set_title('Pearson Correlation')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

    return cor
```

It results in this plot:

[image: Incorrect Plot]

However, on a hunch, I decided to checkout the `cor` dataframe used to make these plots, rather than just discard it. What I found is that the variable with greatest difference of S-P is actually **LotArea**, not **GrLivArea**. For some reason, the plot has been reversed.

```
    feature     spearman    pearson     comparison
0   LotArea     0.456461    0.263843    0.192617
1   GrLivArea   0.731310    0.708624    0.022685
2   GarageArea  0.649379    0.623431    0.025947
```

To fix it, I simply removed the `.sort_values(by='comparison')` argument, and it was fixed. The values/bars are now associated with the correct variables, but the graph is unordered.

[image: Corrected Plot]

I would like to know:

1. **Why is this happening?**
2. **Why is it only happening to the S-P graph?**
3. **How can I plot my graphs in ascending order, so that the variable names are also in the right order?**

I'm lucky to have caught this, but I need help fixing it. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mind posting the dataframe that has each correlations?

Comment: @jcaliz done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not dataframe being sorted, but the `x-ticks` specifically the parameter `sharex=True`, since you are plotting into subplots, they will all share the same order. `pearson` and `spearman` the order were the same, so the only affected was `comparison`.

This should fix that:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(12, 4), )
```

Comment: Wonderful. That argument is a relic from when I had the plots stacked vertically. When I changed to horizontal layout, I forgot to remove sharex. Thank you so much!